# How do I write to the Laravel log from within a Vue component in a Laravel app?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm rather new to both Vue and Laravel and I've discovered that it's considerably harder detecting what's going on in Vue components when they're in a Laravel app. In a Vue-only environment, I can use console.log() to diagnose problems but console.log() doesn't seem to work when the Vue component is in a Laravel app. I have two use cases I'm trying to handle:

1. Troubleshooting where I display text and/or variable values to myself as I try to diagnose logic errors in my coding.
2. Writing to laravel.log when something significant happens, for instance an unexpected response from an Axios statement, such as the database being down.

I have a crude workaround for the first situation - just writing messages to the component itself rather than the console - but that seems very inappropriate for the second case.

What is the proper way to handle both cases?

Comment: "_but console.log() doesn't seem to work when the Vue component is in a Laravel app_" Cannot confirm, `console.log()` works inside Vue/Laravel. There's a "Vue.js Devtools" addon available for browsers. Any errors concerning Laravel should already be posted in your log

Comment: `console.log` is javascript so it works even if the Vue component file is used in a Laravel application. Vue devtools is a must extension when working with Vue whether in a Vue only project or Vue+ Laravel. For any Laravel (server) side error Laravel will automatically make an entry in log if `APP_DEBUG` is set to true in .env file.

Comment: @brombeer - console.log() doesn't work consistently in my Vue components. I was using it to display a message "[Component-name] mounted" in the mounted() section of one of my components and it worked there but the same message in the same place in a second component was ignored as were all other console.log() messages in the second component. That was in Firefox. In Chrome, both mounted() messages appear but the others do not. I'm very confused by this inconsistency and assumed there was a better way to proceed.

Comment: @donkarnash - I have tried devtools but its docs say that if you want to write a message that it will see, you have to code it as follows: Debugbar::debug("Hello"); When I try that in a Vue component, VS Code objects to the syntax, specifically the second colon, and says "Expression expected". This left me with the impression that Debugbar only worked in the PHP-based portions of Laravel and that some other approach was needed for Vue components in Laravel. How do I make Debugbar work in Vue components?

Comment: Firefox "groups" same messages, indicated by a little number on the right side, might be that's why you didn't see it correctly. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools doesn't seem to mention anything of Debugbar - and Debugbar is a Laravel (php) package that has near nothing to do with Vue

Comment: @brombeer - Thank you, that was very helpful. Yes, I had inadvertently turned off the console.log messages by clicking on those buttons (filters!) without realizing what I was doing. Thanks for helping me see that. Also, sorry for muddling up Debugbar and Devtools. I have both but both were quite new to me so I was using one where I should have used the other, plus I'm still learning how to use both. I'm getting the hang of things though; I know a lot more than I did a few days ago!

Comment: You're welcome, happy debugging ;)